# How to create a nested four column table layout?

Tags: html, html-table, html-tbody

I am attempting to create a nested 4 column table layout, see image below.  However, I am not certain, how to add the last row of data, so it is nested under the Date row. I have provided a snippet from a [codepen](https://codesandbox.io/s/twocolumntable-txif3e?file=/src/App.js), which displays the issue.  Can anyone provide any assistance?

**Image**
[image]

**Code Snippet:**

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr colspan="5">
      <th>Regian</th>
      <th>Q1 2010</th>
      <th>Q2 2010</th>
      <th>Q3 2010</th>
      <th>Q4 2010</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody className="labels">
    <tr>
      <td colSpan="5">
        <label htmlFor="accounting">Accounting</label>
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          name="accounting"
          id="accounting"
          data-toggle="toggle"
        ></input>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody className="hide" id="accounting-data">
    <tr>
      <td>Date</td>
      <td>Australia</td>
      <td>$3,544.00</td>
      <td>$5,834.00</td>
      <td>$10,583.00</td>
      <tr>
        <td>Central America</td>
        <td>$7,685.00</td>
        <td>$3,544.00</td>
        <td>$5,834.00</td>
        <td>$10,583.00</td>
      </tr>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got several syntax errors in there, beyond that just missing a `rowspan` on a cell and you had more columns in your html than your example shows. See updated example below. Also not sure if all the separate `tbody` tags serve some sort of purpose but left them in there for ya since technically it's still valid markup. Cheers.

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td, th {
  border: #0f0 1px solid;
  padding: .2rem;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr colspan="5">
      <th>Regian</th>
      <th>Q1 2010</th>
      <th>Q2 2010</th>
      <th>Q3 2010</th>
      <th>Q4 2010</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody className="labels">
    <tr>
      <td colSpan="5">
        <label htmlFor="accounting">Accounting</label>
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          name="accounting"
          id="accounting"
          data-toggle="toggle"
        />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody className="hide" id="accounting-data">
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2" style="vertical-align: top">Date</td>
      <td>Australia</td>
      <td>$3,544.00</td>
      <td>$5,834.00</td>
      <td>$10,583.00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Central America</td>
      <td>$7,685.00</td>
      <td>$3,544.00</td>
      <td>$5,834.00</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```